# Applying Conditional Expectation to Inequality

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose I have an inequality between 2 functions in a certain domain $[a,b]$ e.g. $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. And I have a random variable $X$ that is bounded by the same domain. In addition, there's an event $A$ on which I want to condition $X$. Is it correct to say that $\mathbb{E}[f(X)|A] \leq \mathbb{E}[g(X)|A]$?

You can also assume $\Pr[A]>0$.

Comment: Yes. Is $X$ a continuous random variable on $[a,b]$? Try writing the definition of conditional expecation via integrals.

Comment: In general $\mathbb E[Y\mid A]=\frac{\mathbb EY1_A}{P(A)}$. So $f(X)\leq g(X)$ is a sufficient condition for that.

Comment: Thank you both!